# Trailing comma causing Wordpress custom post to not work as intended

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I've got a custom post that I'm creating. It's used as a page, and you can click on the menu item to get to it. However, in the `rewite` subarray, I left a trailing comma, this seemed to "break" (although no errors were present) wordpresses permalink structure when set to "pretty permalinks". However when set to default, it would function just fine.

**The offending code:**

```
$args = array(
        'labels'               => $labels,
        'description'          => '',
        'public'               => true,
        'hierarchical'         => false,
        'exclude_from_search'  => true,
        'publicly_queryable'   => true,
        'show_ui'              => true,
        'show_in_menu'         => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'    => true,
        'menu_position'        => 21,
        'menu_icon'            => 'dashicons-id',
        'capability_type'      => 'page',
        'capabilities'         => array(),
        'map_meta_cap'         => true,
        'supports'             => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'revisions' ),
        'register_meta_box_cb' => null,
        'taxonomies'           => array( 'profile-position' ),
        'has_archive'          => false,
        'rewrite'              => array( 'slug' => 'profile', ),
        'query_var'            => true,
        'can_export'           => true,
        'delete_with_user'     => false,
    );

    register_post_type( 'profile', $args );

    register_taxonomy(
        'profile-position',
        array( 'profile' ),
        array(
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'labels' => array(
                'name'                       => _x( 'Positions', 'taxonomy general name' ),
                'singular_name'              => _x( 'Position', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
                'search_items'               => __( 'Search Positions' ),
                'all_items'                  => __( 'All Positions' ),
                'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Position' ),
                'update_item'                => __( 'Update Position' ),
                'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Position' ),
                'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Position Name' ),
                'menu_name'                  => __( 'Positions' ),
                'view_item'                  => __( 'View Position' ),
                'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Positions' ),
                'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate positions with commas' ),
                'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove positions' ),
                'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used positions' ),
                'not_found'                  => __( 'No positions found' )
            ),
            'rewrite' => array(
                'hierarchical' => false,
                'slug' => 'profiles/position',
                'with_front' => false
            ),
        )
    );

    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'profile-position', 'profile' );
```

**The functioning code:**

```
// Custom post type for profiles
    $args = array(
        'labels'               => $labels,
        'description'          => '',
        'public'               => true,
        'hierarchical'         => false,
        'exclude_from_search'  => true,
        'publicly_queryable'   => true,
        'show_ui'              => true,
        'show_in_menu'         => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'    => true,
        'menu_position'        => 21,
        'menu_icon'            => 'dashicons-id',
        'capability_type'      => 'page',
        'capabilities'         => array(),
        'map_meta_cap'         => true,
        'supports'             => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'revisions' ),
        'register_meta_box_cb' => null,
        'taxonomies'           => array( 'profile-position' ),
        'has_archive'          => false,
        'rewrite'              => array( 'slug' => 'profile', 'with_front' => false ),
        'query_var'            => true,
        'can_export'           => true,
        'delete_with_user'     => false,
    );

    register_post_type( 'profile', $args );

    register_taxonomy(
        'profile-position',
        array( 'profile' ),
        array(
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'labels' => array(
                'name'                       => _x( 'Positions', 'taxonomy general name' ),
                'singular_name'              => _x( 'Position', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
                'search_items'               => __( 'Search Positions' ),
                'all_items'                  => __( 'All Positions' ),
                'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Position' ),
                'update_item'                => __( 'Update Position' ),
                'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Position' ),
                'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Position Name' ),
                'menu_name'                  => __( 'Positions' ),
                'view_item'                  => __( 'View Position' ),
                'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Positions' ),
                'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate positions with commas' ),
                'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove positions' ),
                'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used positions' ),
                'not_found'                  => __( 'No positions found' )
            ),
            'rewrite' => array(
                'hierarchical' => false,
                'slug' => 'profiles/position',
                'with_front' => false
            ),
        )
    );

    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'profile-position', 'profile' );
```

**the offending line:**
`'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'profile', )`
**the functioning line(s):**
`'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'profile')`
`'rewrite'=> array( 'slug' => 'profile', 'with_front' => false )`

To note - once the comma is removed, with or without the second entry into the rewrite array, expected functionality returns and I can access the page. My understanding is that php ignores trailing commas and it is technically okay to do so (although I typically like to avoid it and this was an error on my part in regards to personal preference).

**So what could be causing the website to return to home page when there is a trailing comma?**

Comment: I tested your code in twentysixteen and nothing broke. I had regular permalinks set: `?profile=test`, and with 'pretty' permalinks `profile/test/` (the name of the post is test). Are you sure there isn't anything else that could be causing this?

Comment: I have no clue! it works locally, but not remotely....I'm at a complete loss...

Comment: Try switching your theme and see if the problem persists. If it doesn't (and in my case the default wp theme showed no errors), then it's the theme issue.